# How to default overview dashboard as group by type in portal.azure.com

Tags: azure, azure-dashboard

I may sound foolish , but could someone quickly help on how to set overview dashboard **group by type** as default in portal.azure.com ?

it's default **no grouping**, but I want it to be **group by type** always
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create default overview dashboard as group by type in Azure Portal :**

Please follow the below steps to create a dashboard as a group type.

1.**Go to** [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) > Click on the  **All resources** button on the left sidebar > Select **Pin blade**

[image]

To check the created dashboard in [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/).

Click on the **"Dashboards"** button on the left sidebar **>** under **"Dashboard section"** choose your dashboard, like below.

[image]

If you need only particular **Resource Group**, kindly follow the below steps.

Click on **setting** button and choose your resource group under resource group filter, like below.

[image]

Once modify the changes, it displays only **Resource Group** details.

[image]

Comment: Awesome!, Thanks for your time ,I learned something new today, though it hasn't helped with my actual problem

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in resource groups, you can however do this in the "All resources" view

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/manage-filter-resource-views

Perform your preferred configuration and save it, then select it as the default view
[image]